# Slave nodes without master running

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I have 1 master node and 2 slave nodes on Jboss EAP 7
All 3 nodes are running and during this.

- -If the master nodes go down suddenly, will the slave nodes be still able to run on their own and work normally? what is the disadvantage of running slave nodes alone in this scenario? is this will be possible?
- -If one of the slave node goes down while the master is down ,can the slave node can be brought up independently and work normally?

Answer (score 0):

If the DC (master node) goes down, the slave nodes will still be Up & Running.
The problem with the slave nodes is that they cannot be restarted unless the master node (DC) is up. Bear in mind that the DC, holds the whole DOMAIN configuration. That's why is very important to consider the HA of the Domain Controller from the beginning.